# How to run app in background?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I want to write app for instant messaging.

So I want my app to start as soon as possible and run in background. But it doesn't seem possible. It tells me backgroud permission is deprecated.

But it seems really weird to me. Don't tell me you can't have some instant messaging app or whatever in Chromebook running in background and just showing notifications about some events.

I found this [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163770), but I don't think it's available right now.

Comment: In a sense, all apps are already running in the background. If your event page registers for an externally triggered event such as a chrome.alarm, you'll find that it works. You might want to register for this event even earlier, such as user login. This is a slightly different problem; on ChromeOS it works as expected, but on other platforms the user must start Chrome. This is not entirely desirable behavior, and we're still looking for the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Push Messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/pushMessaging.html) will wake up your app as needed so that you can perform any logic needed and show a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest file to run background javascript files:

```
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
},
```